Showing $N(p(1-q))=q+(1-p)\cap(1-q)$ if $p,q$ are projections.
If $p$ and $q$ are projections in a von Neumann algebra, I'd like to show that $N(p(1-q))=q+(1-p)\cap(1-q)$, where $N$ denotes the projection onto the null space of the operator. Since $q$ and $(1-p)\cap(1-q)$ commute, $q+(1-p)\cap(1-q)$ is a projection, so we just need to show that the range of $q+(1-p)\cap(1-q)$ is the null space of $p(1-q)$. I can show that the range of $q+(1-p)\cap(1-q)$ is a subset of the null space of $p(1-q)$, but I'm not seeing the other inclusion. Does anyone have an argument for it?

Let $h \in H$. Then $h = qh + (1-q)h$. $h \in N(p(1-q))$ iff $p(1-q)h = 0$ iff $(1-q)h \in (1-p)H$ iff $(1-q)h \in [(1-p) \cap (1-q)]H$. Thus, $h = qh + (1-q)h \in N(p(1-q))$ iff $h \in qH + [(1-p) \cap (1-q)]H = [q + (1-p) \cap (1-q)]H$.
